# Azure Stream Analytics temporal queryes

Tags: sql, azure, powerbi, cortana-intelligence, azure-stream-analytics

i'm new to Azure and i'm not sure if i'm getting right the query system.
I have and application that sends data in every 1.5s to my Service Bus and i need to get my data to PowerBI in real-time.
The simplest query

```
SELECT * FROM DataSource
```

return all data and i can't use it to see real-time events. So i searched and i found about Temporal Queryes, but every example i follow doesn't seems to help me (probably i'm not doing it right). Here's my query:

```
SELECT id, pais, temp, vel, son, lon, lat, hora, dia, colisao, multa, motor, System.timestamp as time, COUNT(*)
FROM fakentrance TIMESTAMP BY time
GROUP BY
id, pais, temp, vel, son, lon, lat, hora, dia, colisao, multa, motor,
TUMBLINGWINDOW(s, 2)
```

Beeing more specific, what i need to do is something like:
If my toy car is accelerating i can have a gauge to show it's increase or decrease in acceleration, or the real temperature of my room, so if it's 30°c and it drops to 16°C it's show this exactly value.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you defined a Power BI output? The simple query should pump all incoming events to its output. You shouldn't need anything more if you only have a sinlge output.

Comment: Do you have a column called "time" with type datetime? What was the behaviour when you started the job with above query, did you see the events in powerBI? Did you see any issues in operation logs and did Azure monitoring page show stats about number of input events, errors etc?

Comment: Vignesh i don't see any strange behaviour, i've edited my query as shown on the under answear and it shows the data on my PowerBI, but it's still showing all data that's in the storage of the server.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have defined both your input and output correctly and include them in your query.

```
 SELECT id, pais, temp, vel, son, lon, lat, hora, dia, colisao, multa, motor, System.timestamp as time, COUNT(*)
    INTO
    <PowerBIOutput>
    FROM <DataSource> TIMESTAMP BY time
    GROUP BY
    id, pais, temp, vel, son, lon, lat, hora, dia, colisao, multa, motor, TUMBLINGWINDOW(s, 2)
```

Comment: i've tryed this and my query is running all ok, but it's not having the behavior i wanted. I'll edit my question to be more specific about it and you comment if it's possible or not to do it. But thanks, it helped, it was not running

Comment: Try using Group By TUMBLINGWINDOW(s,2), id